# Insert text into a filename in unix

Tags: shell

Scenario:

```
#!/usr/bash/ksh
source_dir=/usr/idmp/bbp/

filename = "SURH00000321312"

insertText = `IDD`
```

I want the result like this `SUIDDRH00000321312`. How to add the `insertText` variable into a file name.

Comment: Question: Is the position of `insertText` fixed? i.e. must be behind the first 2 characters?

Answer (score 1):

This does what you ask:

```
$ new=${filename:0:2}$insertText${filename:2}
$ echo "$new"
SUIDDRH00000321312
```

This works by selecting substrings of the variable `filename` starting at an offset and continuing for a length via the shell form: `${parameter:offset:length}`

#### Compatibility

Substring expansion [works under](http://www.appservgrid.com/hyper/hyp/unix-shells#var-expansion) `ksh`, `bash`, and `zsh` but not `dash` or `tcsh`.

Comment: Be aware that this only works under certain shell (e.g. Linux, but not for AIX Unix).

Comment: @J.Chomel The OP's script is a `ksh` script and I test this under `ksh`.  It will [also work](http://www.appservgrid.com/hyper/hyp/unix-shells#var-expansion) under bash and zsh.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way from sed:

```
new_name=$(echo SURH00000321312 |sed -r 's/(.)(.)/\1\2IDD/')
echo $new_name
SUIDDRH00000321312
```