# inserting text in filename using linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a couple of files that needs to be renamed by using a linux shell script. I need to insert the text "ID" next to the second character of the filenames:

```
    HP0001.txt
    HP0002.txt
    HP0003.txt
```

the script should be able to rename it to

```
    HPID0001.txt
    HPID0002.txt
    HPID0003.txt
```

Comment: If it's just "a couple of files" ... it's probably easiest to rename them manually.

Comment: What have you tried?  Which shell are you using?  How many different ways can you think to do it?  Are the existing letters always `HP`?  Are the additional letters always `ID`? Are there always 4 digits?  Is the extension always `.txt`?  How do you plan to invoke the script — will the file names be arguments to the script, or will you give a directory name as the argument?  (In case of doubt, the file names is the better choice.)  Do you have a usable `rename` or `prename` command on your machine?

Comment: This is suspiciously similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176199/insert-text-into-a-filename-in-unix ... Are you guys on the same course? Does your professor approve of getting outside help?

Comment: Do you have [rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) installed?

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a "couple of files", it's probably easiest to just rename them manually.

Otherwise, here's a trivial script you can adapt:

```
for f in HP*.txt; do
  f2=`echo $f|sed -e 's/HP/HPID/'`
  echo mv $f $f2
done
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
ls HP*
HP001.txt  HP002.txt  HP003.txt

bash ./tmp.sh
mv HP001.txt HPID001.txt
mv HP002.txt HPID002.txt
mv HP003.txt HPID003.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

## Files in directory before script execution :

```
HP0001.txt
HP0002.txt
HP0003.txt
main
```

## main script content

```
cat main.sh

for file in *
do

    new_name=$(echo $file|sed 's/HP/&ID/')

    mv $file $new_name 2>/dev/null

done
```

## Directory contents after script execution:

```
ls -1
HPID0001.txt
HPID0002.txt
HPID0003.txt
main
```